# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following python code in selenium;

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2)  
options.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
options.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'C:\\Users\\Own\\data')
options.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/plain')
options.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile', 'text/plain')
service = Service(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Own\\geckodriver-v0.33.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe')
browser = Firefox(service=service, options=options)  # Encounter TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

In the last line, I encounter the error `TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'`

I am using python v3 and selenium v3.141

Answer (score 0):

The error was removed by upgrading selenium to v4